# Problems with mobile portion of a template

Tags: html, css

Having trouble with the background images while scrolling on a mobile device. The images work fine while Inspecting the website and setting it to mobile view, but when I use an actual mobile device the images are zoomed in and blurry.

Im having trouble with the navigation too when Im on a page post.. I cant get back to the main page since the nav links are anchored to the main page in specific spots.

Any help would be amazing! Thanks

http://weareiptv.blogspot.com/

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   #header-inner a img {
     height: auto;
     width: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: great that worked thanks so much!! Would you be able to help me figure out the other problems with the mobile site?

Comment: just noticed also doin this made the logo become miss aligned with the navigation. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: @StevenDarnall set  margin-top: 0px; see here https://imgur.com/a/75CuZ

Comment: If i do that it brings the nav to high when im scrolling down

Comment: thats true.. thats why you need to add padding-top: 20px on your navbar 

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.navbar {
    min-height: 0;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

Comment: still not working real well I just need to bring the logo down to center. again thanks for all your help!

Comment: works on inspect element. try adding padding-top: 20px !important in your navbar under @media only screen and (max-width: 767px)

Comment: just not having any luck with it

Comment: @StevenDarnall i really want to help you.. look at this. hope this help https://imgur.com/a/E78jt

Comment: I got everything firgure out. thanks so much for your help on the logo. Would you be able to help me out with the background images on mobile? Having trouble with the background images while scrolling on a mobile device. The images work fine while Inspecting the website and setting it to mobile view, but when I use an actual mobile device the images are zoomed in and blurry.

Comment: In your style set your background style to background-size: cover

Comment: thanks for responding. I just checked everything is set to cover already.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your logo size.
use [CSS3 Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp).

add this to your css file:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   #header-inner a img {
       height: auto;
    }
}
```

maybe there is a better solution for that. but for me it work.

Comment: where would I add this? tried putting it in the xml but doesnt seem to want to work in there.

Comment: add it to your css file

Comment: I added it to the file but it had no effect on the mobile logo. thanks for trying